# Dom doesn't change when refresh, gunicorn server python3

Tags: html, css, django, python-3.x

My problem is in the DOM. When i do some modifications on my elements in a htmlfile and then i refresh my page nothing happen but after a few secondes the modifications appears and a few seconde later disappears.

For exemple i have some images. I chose one and delete it. I go on my web page, refresh, nothing happen first. i refresh again and my image is finaly disappears.

```
<div class="row logo-bar">
                <div class="col-xs-offset-0 col-xs-4 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-2 hidden-md-down">
                    <img class="img-responsive logo-bar-logo" alt="{{page_text.logo_line2_logo1_alt}}" src="{% if type == 'elec' or type == 'elec_edf_bleuciel' or type == 'elec_edf' %}{% static 'Site/images/landing_pages/logo_edf.png' %}{%else%}{% static 'Site/images/pages/logo-gdf.png' %}{%endif%}"/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2">
                    <img class="img-responsive logo-bar-logo" alt="{{page_text.logo_line2_logo2_alt}}" src="{% if type == 'elec' or type == 'elec_edf_bleuciel' or type == 'elec_edf' %}{% static 'Site/images/home/logo_de.png' %}{%else%}{% static 'Site/images/landing_pages/logo_edf.png' %}{%endif%}"/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2">
                    <img class="img-responsive logo-bar-logo" alt="{{page_text.logo_line2_logo3_alt}}" src="{% if type == 'elec' or type == 'elec_edf_bleuciel' or type == 'elec_edf' %}{% static 'Site/images/pages/logo-gdf.png' %}{%else%}{% static 'Site/images/home/logo_de.png' %}{%endif%}"/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-4 col-sm-offset-0 col-sm-2">
                    <img class="img-responsive logo-bar-logo" alt="{{page_text.logo_line2_logo4_alt}}" src="{% if type == 'elec' or type == 'elec_edf_bleuciel' or type == 'elec_edf' %}{% static 'Site/images/landing_pages/logo_erdf.png' %}{%else%}{% static 'Site/images/home/logo_grdf.png' %}{%endif%}"/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2">
                    <img class="img-responsive logo-bar-logo" alt="{{page_text.logo_line2_logo5_alt}}" src="{% if type == 'elec' or type == 'elec_edf_bleuciel' or type == 'elec_edf' %}{% static 'Site/images/home/logo_grdf.png' %}{%else%}{% static 'Site/images/landing_pages/logo_erdf.png' %}{%endif%}"/>
                </div>
            </div>
```

The most incredible thing is the bootstrap's class. I use some of its on some elements and nothing happen.
When i use the chrome's inspector, the modifications i put in my IDE doesn't appears on my html page.
If i use ctrl r a lot some time the modifications appear, some time not.

```
<h4 class="form-direction hidden-lg">Ou complétez le formulaire,<br/>un conseiller vous rappelle gratuitement</h4>

<h4 class="hidden-xs">Complétez le formulaire,<br/>un conseiller vous rappelle gratuitement</h4>


    <!-- css -->
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
{#<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'Site/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">#}
{#<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'Site/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css' %}">#}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'Site/css/jquery_popup.css' %}"/>

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:500,600,400,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Maybe a cache problem ?

My server works well. My script js works well and i use bootstrap's class in.....

My script

```
$("document").ready(function($){

    var nav = $('.title-header');
    var bar = $('.navbar-header ');

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() < 600) {
            nav.addClass("hidden-xs");
            bar.addClass("hidden-xs");
        } else {
            nav.removeClass("hidden-xs");
            bar.removeClass("hidden-xs");
        }
    });

});
```

My server

```
python3 manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
July 05, 2016 - 18:52:51
Django version 1.8, using settings 'Project.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
/home/baptiste/projects/souscri/site/souscri/web/Site/urls.py:15: RemovedInDjango19Warning: Default value of 'RedirectView.permanent' will change from True to False in Django 1.9. Set an explicit value to silence this warning.
  url(r'^offres/electricite-gaz/gdf-suez-dolce-vita', RedirectView.as_view(url='/offres/electricite-gaz/engie')),

[05/Jul/2016 18:52:56]"GET /campagnes/demenagement-edf-electricite-gaz/ HTTP/1.1" 200 9542
[05/Jul/2016 18:52:56]"GET /static/Site/css/landing_page.css HTTP/1.1" 200 6218
[05/Jul/2016 18:52:56]"GET /static/Site/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 35452
[05/Jul/2016 18:52:56]"GET /static/Site/js/parsley.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 43690
[05/Jul/2016 18:52:56]"GET /static/Site/js/typeahead.bundle.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 29675
[05/Jul/2016 18:52:56]"GET /static/Site/js/jquery.inputmask-min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 42045
[05/Jul/2016 18:52:56]"GET /static/Site/js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 84320
[05/Jul/2016 18:52:56]"GET /static/Site/js/typeahead-addresspicker.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 4650
[05/Jul/2016 18:52:56]"GET /static/Site/css/jquery_popup.css HTTP/1.1" 200 1348
[05/Jul/2016 18:52:56]"GET /static/Site/js/bootstrap-select-min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 23916
[05/Jul/2016 18:52:56]"GET /static/Site/js/script-landing.js HTTP/1.1" 200 382
[05/Jul/2016 18:52:56]"GET /static/Site/images/layout/logo.png HTTP/1.1" 200 2643
[05/Jul/2016 18:52:56]"GET /static/Site/images/landing_pages/logo_erdf.png HTTP/1.1" 200 12790
[05/Jul/2016 18:52:56]"GET /static/Site/images/landing_pages/logo_edf.png HTTP/1.1" 200 6670
[05/Jul/2016 18:52:56]"GET /static/Site/images/home/logo_de.png HTTP/1.1" 200 5117
[05/Jul/2016 18:52:56]"GET /static/Site/images/pages/logo-gdf.png HTTP/1.1" 200 12104
[05/Jul/2016 18:52:56]"GET /static/Site/images/home/logo_grdf.png HTTP/1.1" 200 7111
[05/Jul/2016 18:52:56]"GET /static/Site/images/landing_pages/operateur.png HTTP/1.1" 200 14997
```

If i do some change in my js or css file the server do it but if i do some change in my html file, i have to restart the server and refresh my page to see them.

Comment: Have you tried to disable the cache in the chrome inspector ? console>network > disable cache 
Also try to restart your server

Comment: yes i try both of them.